# Convert .PSD File To .JPEG/.PNG File Programmatically

Tags: java, android, psd

How do I convert `.psd` file to an image, like .jpeg or .png or any other image format, programmatically?

I tried to find some java library like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

If conversation is not possible, I would like to find some way to read psd files directly on any `viewer`.

Need A More Suitable Suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Ok, if you don't mind getting your hands dirty, you could see if you can use my [PSDImageReader](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#adobe-photoshop-document-psd) for ImageIO as a starting point, and develop an Android version from that. If you only need the "composite layer" of the PSD, the format is quite easy to parse and read.

Answer (score 2):

[Aspose](https://docs.aspose.com/display/psdjava/Creating%2C+Opening+and+Saving+Images) looks promising, providing conversion to-and-from many popular formats.

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("converted", "-format ", "jpg ", psdafterconvpath, psdpath + "\\" + "*.psd");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }
```